# Google compute engine - click to deploy - lamp error

Tags: cloud, google-compute-engine, lamp

When I was trying to deploy an instance of LAMP. It always come with following error:

```
Creating deployment
Aug 7, 2015, 3:40:26 PM
deploymentCoordinator: PENDING
lamp: PENDING
Aug 7, 2015, 3:40:37 PM ... Aug 7, 2015, 3:41:20 PM
deploymentCoordinator: DEPLOYING
lamp: DEPLOYING
Aug 7, 2015, 3:41:32 PM
deploymentCoordinator: DEPLOYMENT_FAILED
Replica lamp-coord-udn0 failed with status PERMANENTLY_FAILING: Replica State changed to PERMANENTLY_FAILING. Replica was unhealthy 2 consecutive times.
lamp: DEPLOYING
```

Tried few times, always the same error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the instances created by the last deployment that failed?  In other words, in the console if you go to Compute > VM instances, do you see something like lamp-coord-abcd and lamp-abcd?

If so, can you ssh into lamp-**coord**-abcd and run the following command:

```
tail -f /gagent/metaOutput/*
```

Then paste back here what the output is.  This will help diagnose why this deployment is not working for you.